# Android Gesture Detection in class, call methods

Tags: android, class, gesture

I try to detect the gestures in android and the it crashes all the time, i have problems with creating an constructor, i'am not so advanced in using classes

this is the GestureDetector class, width all the necessary methods for the OnGestureListener:

```
public class GestureDetectorClass implements OnGestureListener {

      @Override
      public boolean onDown(MotionEvent arg0) {
          Log.d("Gesture", "onDown");
       return false;
      }

      @Override
      public boolean onFling(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float velocityX,  float velocityY) {
          Log.d("Gesture", "onFling");
      return true;
      }

      @Override
      public void onLongPress(MotionEvent e) {
          Log.d("Gesture", "onLongPress");
      }

      @Override
      public boolean onScroll(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2,
        float distanceX, float distanceY) {
          Log.d("Gesture", "onScroll");
       return false;
      }

      @Override
      public void onShowPress(MotionEvent e) { 
          Log.d("Gesture", "onShowPress");
      }

      @Override
      public boolean onSingleTapUp(MotionEvent e) {
          Log.d("Gesture", "onSingleTapUp");
          return false;
      }

}
```

and in the main i try now to call the class / methods
tried following code:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity  {


    GestureDetectorClass myGestureClass = new GestureDetectorClass();
    GestureDetector myDector = new GestureDetector(this, myGestureClass);

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    }

    public boolean onTouch(MotionEvent e) {
        return myDector.onTouchEvent(e);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

}
```

in the log i found this error:

```
    11-13 11:15:02.615: E/AndroidRuntime(1127): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
11-13 11:15:02.615: E/AndroidRuntime(1127):     at android.content.ContextWrapper.getApplicationInfo(ContextWrapper.java:125)
```

Comment: you might have to call OnGestureListener's default construction in your GestureDetectorClass's default construction

Comment: thanks for your comment, but how to i do this? something like "OnGestureListener mylistener;"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A suggestion I would create new object of myDetector after I set content view because you are using `this` in `new GestureDetector(this, myGestureClass);` this might be the reason for nullpointerexception

```
GestureDetector myDector;
GestureDetectorClass myGestureClass;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    myGestureClass = new GestureDetectorClass();
    myDector = new GestureDetector(this, myGestureClass);

}
```

Here is and example 
http://android-er.blogspot.com/2012/07/implement-gesturedetectorongestureliste.html

Comment: thanks, yes that was the problem, and i also now understand why i happend!